# The polynomial $x^{242}=1$ has exactly $242 $ solutions in $K$ True/false

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $K$ be  a  field  of  order $243$   and let  $F$ be  a  subfield  of $K $ of order $3$.Pick  the correct statements  from below

$1.$ There exist $\alpha \in K$ such that $K=F(\alpha)$

$2. $The  polynomial $x^{242}=1$ has  exactly $242 $ solutions in $K$

$3.$The polynomial $x^{26}=1$ has  exactly  $26$ roots  in $K$

$4.$let $f(x) \in F(x)$  be  an irreducible  polynomial  of  degree $5$.Then  $f(x)$  has  a root in $K$

**My attempt**

$1.$ True because We know that $K^*$ is cyclic, choose $\alpha\not=0$ such that $K^*=<\alpha>$. Then $K=F(\alpha)$.

$2.$Iam confused

$3.$ False  because we have $|K^*|=242=2\cdot 11^2$ hence $x^{26}=1\iff x^2=1\iff x=\pm 1$.

$4.$ True. from isomorphism theorem we have $g:F[x]/(f(x))\rightarrow K \implies g(x) \in K$.

How  to solve option $2$

Comment: Look at your answer to 1, then look at question 2 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to 2. is TRUE. That $K$ is a field with $243$ elements gives $K\setminus \{0\}$ having $242$ elements. Now $K^*= K\setminus \{0\}$ is a group under multiplication, with $242$ elements. [It's actually cyclic, but to show that the answer is true, all you need is that the  equation $|K^*|=242$.] So for each of the $242$ elements $\alpha \in K^*$, it follows that $\alpha^{|K^*|} =$ $\alpha^{242}$ must be the multiplicative identity $1$. So $\alpha^{242}=1$ for each of the $242$ elements $\alpha \in K^*$, or equivalently, $\alpha^{242}-1=0$ for each of the $242$ elements $\alpha \in K^*$. Thus the polynomial $x^{242}-1$ has $242$ roots in $K^*$, namely every $\alpha \in K^*$.

Comment: I have  some confusion @Mike   suppose if i take   $\mathbb{Z}_{242}$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{242} $ is cyclic group but  $x^{242}=1$ is not  satisfied for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{242}$

Comment: @wasiu Why not? By Euler, $a^{|G|}=1$ for all $a\in G$.

Comment: @wasiu Note that the group $K^{\times}$ is *multiplicative*, so $C_{242}$, rather than $\Bbb Z_{242}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/242$ has order $242$ but for this, the group operation is *addition*. Add any element to itself $242$ times and you will get $0$ which is the identity element in $\mathbb{Z}/242$.

Comment: OKAY THANKS YOU @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a polynomial can be written as a product of the difference between x and its roots: $$P_n(x)=a_n(x-\frac{r_1}{a_n})(x-r_2)(x-r_3)...=a_n(x-\frac{r_1}{a_n})\prod^{n}_{r_i=r_2}(x-r_i)$$ Where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial and $a_n$ is the first term. This is true since substituting a root for $x$ would make one of the factors to be zero, making the whole polynomial equal to zero. Now there are $n$ factors here, so there are at most $n$ roots to an $n$th degree polynomial.

Note: by the fundamental theorem of algebra, $x^{242}$ has $242$ (not necessarily distinct) roots.